# Deep copy of a linked list with a random pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

This is a leetcode interview question that asks for a deep copy of a linked list which has a `random` member which could point to any element. (https://leetcode.com/problems/copy-list-with-random-pointer). I can't figure out why my solution gives a runtime error for misaligned access.

Here's my solution:

```
/*
// Definition for a Node.
class Node {
public:
    int val;
    Node* next;
    Node* random;

    Node() {}

    Node(int _val, Node* _next, Node* _random) {
        val = _val;
        next = _next;
        random = _random;
    }
};
*/
class Solution {
public:
    Node* copyRandomList(Node* head) {
        unordered_map<Node*, Node*> node_map;
        Node* copy_head = new Node();

        Node* node = head;
        Node* copy = copy_head;

        while (node) {
            node_map[node] = copy;
            copy->val = node->val;
            if (node->next)
                copy->next = new Node();
            node = node->next;
            copy = copy->next;
        }

        node = head;
        copy = copy_head;

        while (node) {
            copy->random = node_map[node->random];
            node = node->next;
            copy = copy->next;
        }

        return copy_head;        
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first `while` loop is not the preferred or canonical way to allocate a  new copy of a linked list. There should only be 1 call to `new`, inside the loop, not outside of it. If `head` is null, you are still allocating a `Node` you should not be.

More importantly, your `Node`'s default constructor, which your copy code uses, does not initialize any of the data members, especially the `next` pointer in particular. So your last copied node will have a random indeterminate value that is likely to not be null, so it won't be null-terminating the list properly.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
/*
// Definition for a Node.
class Node {
public:
    int val;
    Node* next;
    Node* random;

    Node() {}

    Node(int _val, Node* _next, Node* _random) {
        val = _val;
        next = _next;
        random = _random;
    }
};
*/

class Solution {
public:
    Node* copyRandomList(Node* head) {
        if (!head)
            return nullptr;

        unordered_map<Node*, Node*> node_map;
        Node* copy_head = nullptr;
        Node** copy = &copy_head;
        Node* node = head;

        do {
            *copy = new Node(node->val, nullptr, nullptr);
            node_map.insert(make_pair(node, *copy));
            copy = &((*copy)->next);
            node = node->next;
        }
        while (node);

        node = copy_head;

        do {
            if (head->random)
                node->random = node_map[head->random];
            node = node->next;
            head = head->next;
        }
        while (head);

        return copy_head;
    }
};
```

Comment: If you follow the link provided by OP, you will realize that he/she cannot change the definition of `Node` class.

Comment: @DanielLangr nothing on that page says the definition can't be changed

Comment: @DanielLangr tried what? Reading the linked page? Yes, I did. Tried the code? [Yes , I did](http://ideone.com/fK5oZ7)

Comment: Tried to redefine `Node` class in the OP's environment (not ideone but [that page](https://leetcode.com/problems/copy-list-with-random-pointer)). It's not defined in the source code, but somewhere outside. When I tried to redefine it (as you originally suggested by adding a default arguments to the constructor), then I got a compilation error complaining about redefinition of `Node`.

Comment: @DanielLangr fine. I updated my answer to account for that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your copy is not terminated with a null pointer. That is, its last node does not store `nullptr` in its `next` member variable.

You create nodes of a copy by `new node()`, which invokes a default constructor. However, this default constructor does nothing, including no initialization of member variables. Therefore, you need to set `next` of your last node to `nullptr` manually.